# 1fr grid css dont' span whole screen

Tags: html, css, grid

I got three main element and in the html

in the LAST MEDIA QUERY in my css below i'd expect the 'welcome' black element 'MOONY lorem ipsum' to span whole screen and send the other two elements, 'about' and 'photo', below, since i put grid-template-columns to 1fr, but this doesn't happen, the welcome black 'MOONY lorem ipsum' element still take 1/3 on the left and the second element 'about' with the 'picture of the guy from the back' takes 2/3 on the right. why?

below i put html css and a picture

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;500;600;800&family=VT323&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1fr;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
/* .x'whitespace'.y means y class which is inside x class */
.panel .text {
  background: #eeeee7;
  color: #323230;
  padding: 30px 60px;
}


/* welcome panel */
.panel.welcome {
  background: #323230;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
.panel.welcome nav a {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.panel.welcome p {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  max-width: 540px;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.panel.welcome h1 {
  color: #eeeee7;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.panel.welcome footer {
  align-self: end;
}
/* about panel */
.panel.about {
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel.about img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* photo panel */

.panel.photos {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel.photos img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .panel.photos {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Portfolio Full-Screen Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="panel welcome">
        <nav>
          <a href="">Home</a>
          <a href="">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <h1>Moony</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi
            ducimus deleniti unde alias nam reiciendis qui molestias neque!
            Laudantium dicta recusandae earum nulla animi molestias est placeat
            cum excepturi libero?
          </p>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
      <div class="panel about">
        <img src="./img/1.png" alt="main pic">
        <div class="text">
          <h2>About</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quos consequuntur repellat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel photos">
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Photography</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, consequatur? lorem15</p>
        </div>
        <img src="./img/2.png" alt="lanscape pic">
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted the base parameters (main and panel).  And we adjusted the @media by using 'grid-area' instead.  The last @media I didn't adjust as it needs more parameter.  End result we made is a two row @media result.

Your note didn't indicate exactly how you wanted that lower panel once @media kicks in, so you'll need to re-adjust it to fit your specific intent.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;500;600;800&family=VT323&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr;
}
/* .x'whitespace'.y means y class which is inside x class */
.panel .text {
  background: #eeeee7;
  color: #323230;
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

/* welcome panel */
.panel.welcome {
  background: #323230;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
.panel.welcome nav a {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.panel.welcome p {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  max-width: 540px;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.panel.welcome h1 {
  color: #eeeee7;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.panel.welcome footer {
  align-self: end;
}
/* about panel */
.panel.about {
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel.about img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* photo panel */

.panel.photos {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel.photos img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .panel.welcome {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-area: 1 / span 2;
  }
  .panel.about {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-area: 2 / 1;
  }
  .panel.photos {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-area: 2 / 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
      <div class="panel welcome">
        <nav>
          <a href="">Home</a>
          <a href="">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <h1>Moony</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi
            ducimus deleniti unde alias nam reiciendis qui molestias neque!
            Laudantium dicta recusandae earum nulla animi molestias est placeat
            cum excepturi libero?
          </p>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
      <div class="panel about">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.gifg" alt="main pic">
        <div class="text">
          <h2>About</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quos consequuntur repellat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel photos">
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Photography</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, consequatur? lorem15</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.gif" alt="landscape pic">
      </div>
    </main>
```